# Is there any way I can add multiplier in spacing selection of StackView in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

Actually, I want to add a multiplier in the spacing selection of StackView, so is there any way of implementing that?

[image]

Comment: No, there is no way of doing that as far as I know, but why you need multiplier for spacing inside stackView?

Comment: Multiplier is required as for smaller device spacing must be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add stack view spacing as a multiplier programmatically in Swift, see below:

```
myStackView.spacing = constantSpacing * multiplier
```

Comment: I guess below code is working fine for me: 
myStackView.spacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.02